# Localization in ASP.NET CORE application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I been trying for days to resolve localization in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Car Sales project....it copmprises only one controller and three resource files. Default language is Serbian, the other two, german and english. Resx files are located in Resources folder within the project(Resource.resx,Resource.en-Us.resx,Resource.de-DE.resx. After debugging project, there's no visible mistake were display[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7D2C.jpg)ed.

AutomobilController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CarSales.Models;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace CarSales.Controllers
{
    public class AutomobilController : Controller
    {
        public IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer;


        private readonly AutomobilContext db;

        public AutomobilController(AutomobilContext context, IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer)
        {
            db = context;
            this.localizer = localizer;
        }

        public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture,string sourceUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)), new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) } );

            return Redirect(sourceUrl);
        }

        public FileContentResult CitajAutomobil(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Automobil auto = db.Automobili.Find(Id);

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return File(auto.Fotografija, auto.TipFajla);
        }

        // GET: Automobil
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            ViewBag.teststring = localizer["Detalji"];
            return View(await db.Automobili.ToListAsync());
            
        }

        // GET: Automobil/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var automobil = await db.Automobili
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (automobil == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(automobil);
        }

        // GET: Automobil/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult ONama()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Kontakt()
        {
            return View();
        }



        // POST: Automobil/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Fotografija,TipFajla,Marka,Model,Godiste,ZapreminaMotora,Snaga,Gorivo,Karoserija,Opis,Cena,Kontakt")] Automobil automobil, IFormFile OdabraniAutomobil)
        {
            if (OdabraniAutomobil == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Fotografija", "Niste odabrali sliku");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await OdabraniAutomobil.CopyToAsync(ms);
                        automobil.Fotografija = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    automobil.TipFajla = OdabraniAutomobil.ContentType;

                    db.Add(automobil);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ViewBag.Greska = "Greska pri cuvanju slike Automobila";
                    
                }
                
            }
            return View(automobil);
        }

        // GET: Automobil/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var automobil = await db.Automobili.FindAsync(id);
            if (automobil == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(automobil);
        }

        // POST: Automobil/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Fotografija,TipFajla,Marka,Model,Godiste,ZapreminaMotora,Snaga,Gorivo,Karoserija,Opis,Cena,Kontakt")] Automobil automobil)
        {
            if (id != automobil.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Update(automobil);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!AutomobilExists(automobil.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(automobil);
        }

        // GET: Automobil/Delete/5
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var automobil = await db.Automobili
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (automobil == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(automobil);
        }

        // POST: Automobil/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var automobil = await db.Automobili.FindAsync(id);
            db.Automobili.Remove(automobil);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool AutomobilExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Automobili.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using CarSales.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CarSales.Models;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CarSales
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<AutomobilContext>(opcije => opcije.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));

            services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources");



            services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(opts => { opts.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(Resource)); }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opts =>
                {
                    var supported = new\[\]
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en"),
                        new CultureInfo("sr"),
                        new CultureInfo("de-DE")
                    };

                    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "sr", uiCulture: "sr");
                    opts.SupportedCultures = supported;
                    opts.SupportedUICultures = supported;
                }

                );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRequestLocalization();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Automobil}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}][2]
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: What happens when you run that? Is it always in the default language? Also, you shouldn't need to change `DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider`

Comment: It run smoothly without a problem, but it does not change phrases from resx files.

Comment: See if it helps you, I wrote some short instructions that worked for me: https://alexrait.blogspot.com/2021/06/aspnet-core-localization.html

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it.